# Laravel development server closing

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a laravel 6 api only application so I am testing the endpoints using postman. I am getting this error when I make request to any of the endpoints

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\Elo\apiProject\server.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

From vscode terminal I can see that the development server starts, accepts then closes as seen below

```
$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Thu Apr  2 21:05:53 2020] PHP 7.4.0 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Thu Apr  2 21:05:59 2020] 127.0.0.1:53500 Accepted
[Thu Apr  2 21:05:59 2020] 127.0.0.1:53500 Closing
[Thu Apr  2 21:27:23 2020] 127.0.0.1:53668 Accepted
[Thu Apr  2 21:27:23 2020] 127.0.0.1:53668 Closing
```

I have no idea why it is closing and no information inside the log file. What could be responsible for throwing such error?

Comment: if not logs in  `your-project/storage/logs/laravel.log`, could be a permissions issue. did you set the right permissions to storage folder?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I meant no errors related to this issue in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I think it's related to the port 8000.
Maybe it's already in use or something like this because when I changed the port to 9000 (ie: `php artisan server --port=9000`) it solved the issue and works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.In my case it was when I started to work in the project from another computer and so, I did "git clone".

I solved the problem by creating a ".env" copying the .env.example and then, I executed the command "php artisan key:generate" to generate the new API_KEY, which is mandatory for the start of the server.

Hope it helped you !